# Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs returning $null in Automation Accounts

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I have a simple script to get the last sign in details for each user in Azure. When running the script from Visual Studio, it all runs fine with no errors.
After uploading the script to an Azure Automation Account, I am getting the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

I have checked and the command 'Get-AzureADAuditSigninLogs' is returning $null

```
$users = Get-AzureADUser -All $true
foreach ( $user in $users ) {
    $userLogs = Get-AzureADAuditSigninLogs -Filter "startsWith(userPrincipalName, '$( $user.UserPrincipalName )')" -All $true
}
```

Any ideas on the issue that could be causing this to occur in the Automation account but not visual studio?

Comment: Did you mean to do `Get-AzureADUser -All:$true` instead of just `Get-AzureADUser`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes Thankyou. although this doesn't make a difference for my environment.

Comment: Perhaps because you're overwriting the previous results every time you query the logs for the next user? Move `$userLogs =` assignment outside the loop to capture all of them instead: `$userLogs = foreach($user in $users){ Get-AzureADAuditSigninLogs ... }`

Comment: After the $userLogs assignment, I am saving the results elsewhere. This would not make a difference to the output of "Get-AzureADAuditSigninLogs" however. Somewhere during the execution of this command it is erroring, and therefore just returning $null.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell-azuread/issues/337),`-All $true` parameter is not working for cmdlet `Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs` as expected.

To resolve it, you can try upgrading to AzureADPreview `v2.0.2.89`.

Alternatively, you can also try as suggested by [psignoret](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell-azuread/issues/727):

**Format string with -f or [String]::Format():**

```
Write-Host ("startsWith(userPrincipalName ,'{0}')" -f $user.userPrincipalName)
```

```
Write-Host [String]::Format("startsWith(userPrincipalName ,'{0}')", $user.userPrincipalName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to use $User.UserPrincipalName with the filter in Get-AzureADAuditSigninLogs command. You need to first save the value to another variable and then use that. And when you have already used -All in the Get-AzureADUser command then no need if you want to list just the last login date. If you want all logs for all users, then remove the "-Top" parameter I've used. Here is the correction:-

```
$users = Get-AzureADUser -All $true
foreach($user in $users) {
    $UPN = $user.UserPrincipalName
    $userLogs = Get-AzureADAuditSigninLogs -Filter "startsWith(UserPrincipalName, '$UPN')" -Top 1
}
```